# TL-WN722N blocking processes on Kali Linux 2.0

Tags: wifi, virtualbox, kali-linux, firmware, airmon-ng

today I'm looking for some serious help with getting my TP-Link TL-WN722N to work on my Kali Linux 2.0 VM. Just for some background, I'm running Kali Linux 2 within my Mac OS (Yosemite) using VirtualBox. The steps I took are as follows:

- installed the image with 20GB of Storage and 2GB of RAM
- updated and installed linux headers via `apt-get update && apt-get install -y linux-headers-$(uname -r)`
- installed the Virtualbox Guest additions
- rebooted Kali Linux
- connected the usb device
- ran airmon-ng and iwconfig

This, however, is where I run into issues. Running either of these commands will essentially freeze the terminal until I manually disconnect the device from its usb port. When I check `dmesg` to see what's going on after unplugging the device, it shows some errors, specifically saying that various processes have been blocked as shown in the image below.

[image: dmseg]

Now I'm not entirely sure what `kworker` or `vminfo` are, however their being blocked seems to be what's causing this "freeze" or possible deadlock situation?

After some research, I believe the issue to be with the firmware-atheros package. I tried removing the package and installing the jessie backports version of the firmware-atheros package, however after doing this the device would not connect at all.

I can provide any additional images, syslogs, etc., I just really would appreciate the help here as I'd like to learn more about network security and pen testing, and Kali seems to be a prime option for me. Thanks!